# What Ubuntu Kernel Extensions were installed to enable SSD to run on non-AHCI motherboard?

Tags: kernel, ahci

A [Dell Optiplex 390](https://pastebin.com/dMcxLhNw) is successfully outfitted with an SSD + 16.04.   The internet indicates motherboard does not feature AHCI capability and that kernel extension are necessary to implement AHCI.

If this is true, how does one determine (from the Ubuntu CLI) which Ubuntu kernel extensions are installed and which subset enables AHCI?

Comment: Kext files are essentially drivers for Mac OS X. Unless there is another explanation, I am voting to close as not about Ubuntu.

Comment: Question updated to reflect request for Ubuntu Terminal commands and not OS X

Comment: Do you mean kernel modules? Are you asking how to list loaded modules and how to load modules?

Comment: @muru: Yes.  I believe they are the synonymous?  If not, I can modify the question.

Comment: I don't think I have ever heard anyone call kernel modules "extensions".